# Python3.8: MetPy issue: declarative plotting of grib2 file plotting blank map

Tags: python, metpy

Teaching myself the declarative plotting feature in MetPy, and keep hitting a snag.  This comes from trying to apply the declarative plotting package to a grib2 file, after opening via xarray/cfgrib.  The data *appears* healthy, but it seems the the actual temperature data isn't being passed and plotted. When I plot it, I get a blank map.

I've got the compressed code below, along with a few print outs of the data examination to show that the data seems ok.

Am I missing something? (I'm sure I am, but I'm wondering what?)

Thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pygrib
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeat
import cartopy
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import io
from metpy.units import units
from metpy.plots import ImagePlot, MapPanel, PanelContainer

##Open GFS grib2 file, initialized 2021060700, and pull data from hPa level designation.
ds = xr.open_dataset('/fewxops/Tom/learn_python/data/grib2/gfs.t00z.pgrb2.0p25.f024', engine='cfgrib', filter_by_keys={'typeOfLevel': 'isobaricInhPa'})

##Select individual level (from designated 'type of level')
ds_z500=ds.sel(isobaricInhPa=500)

##Create base image via MetPy
img = ImagePlot()
img.data = ds_z500
img.field = 't'
img.colormap = 'plasma'

#Create map panel (e.g. subplot in matplotlib)
panel = MapPanel()
panel.area = 'us'
#panel.layers = ['states']
panel.title = 'GFS 500mb Temp Forecast Example'
panel.plots = [img]

##Create panel container (e.g. figure in matplotlib)
pc = PanelContainer()
pc.size = (10,8)
pc.panels = [panel]
pc.show()

*******************************
home/fewx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/metpy/xarray.py:349: UserWarning: More than one time coordinate present for variable "t".
  warnings.warn('More than one ' + axis + ' coordinate present for variable'
Found valid latitude/longitude coordinates, assuming latitude_longitude for projection grid_mapping variable
```

```
print(ds_z500)
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (latitude: 721, longitude: 1440)
Coordinates:
    time           datetime64[ns] ...
    step           timedelta64[ns] ...
    isobaricInhPa  float64 500.0
  * latitude       (latitude) float64 90.0 89.75 89.5 ... -89.5 -89.75 -90.0
  * longitude      (longitude) float64 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 ... 359.2 359.5 359.8
    valid_time     datetime64[ns] ...
Data variables:
    gh             (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    t              (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    r              (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    q              (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    w              (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    wz             (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    u              (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    v              (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    absv           (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    o3mr           (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
Attributes:
    GRIB_edition:            2
    GRIB_centre:             kwbc
    GRIB_centreDescription:  US National Weather Service - NCEP
    GRIB_subCentre:          0
    Conventions:             CF-1.7
    institution:             US National Weather Service - NCEP
    history:                 2021-06-15T08:05 GRIB to CDM+CF via cfgrib-0.9.9...


print(ds_z500['t'].values)
[[245.93057 245.93057 245.93057 ... 245.93057 245.93057 245.93057]
 [245.85057 245.84056 245.84056 ... 245.85057 245.85057 245.85057]
 [245.72057 245.72057 245.71057 ... 245.73056 245.73056 245.72057]
 ...
 [226.94057 226.94057 226.94057 ... 226.94057 226.94057 226.94057]
 [226.96057 226.96057 226.96057 ... 226.96057 226.96057 226.96057]
 [226.88057 226.88057 226.88057 ... 226.88057 226.88057 226.88057]]
```

[GFS Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSLag.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not missing anything, you just ran into a limitation in some code in `ImagePlot` that's trying to help with CartoPy--specifically regarding plotting using `imshow` with lat/lon data. Your example code *should* be working fine, and does for `ContourPlot`. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/1915) for further investigation for how to solve this problem for the next release.

In the meanwhile, one workaround would be to subset the data before plotting to eliminate MetPy's problematic "helping" for the wrapping (around -180/+180 and 0/360 longitude):

```
# The order in these slices needs to match that of the data
ds_z500 = ds_z500.metpy.sel(longitude=slice(250, 315), latitude=slice(60, 10))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I can confirm the lat/lon slice does indeed fix the problem (and is a nice trick to help with brevity).  As a side, I noticed that MetPy's declarative plotting plotted the data more quickly than a simple matplotlib/cartopy contourf seemed to, which can be a grind and take noticeable time on complex plots (not great).  Am I imagining that (?), or does not MetPy *not* engage contourf for its image/filled plotting (I had just blindly assumed it had)?  Just curious!

Comment: I would not have expected MetPy's `ContourPlot` to be any faster since it's just directly using CartoPy. My first guess is that some other steps/use of a transform somehow gets on a happy path. That's interesting to know.

Comment: Also, don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.